# Pedestal Sink Base Removal

Tags: plumbing, sink, plumbing-fixture

I am working on my bathroom floor and need to temporarily remove the pedestal sink base.  The bowl is attached to the wall via a mounting bracket on the underside of the bowl. Is it possible to remove just the base and keep the bowl in place or does the base help support it?  It does not appear to help support the weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To facilitate work on plumbing, I have removed and later replaced the pedestal from several pedestal basins with no problem other than clearing any carpet or other flooring or woodwork around the bottom to make it possible to slide the pedestal out.

Sometimes they are a close fit but so far none have really been needed to support the basin.

Comment: That's how it appears but wanted to double check.  Thanks